# Submitting File Upload Form with C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am trying to automate/webscrape a process that we have internally to a third party website, but I am getting stuck on the forms `onChange` event.

The form that I have to post to has an element like this...

`<input type="file" id="import_file" name="import_file" onchange="file_input_changed(event);">`

The onchange event triggers some checks and creates some AWS signatures

Is there a way I can post the file to the input element and once the signatures have been created, then I can submit the form?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Please advise

Comment: When trying to automatically submit forms, the easiest way is to use `CefSharp` (Chromium based webbrowser for c#) and fill the form through the available javascript API. That way, ajax based events are triggered as they should be. It requires some work because cef sharps api is highly async (even reading the source of a page requires an async SourceVisitor), but it's doable.